# Javascript & Django - Confirm() cancel should not follow href

Tags: javascript, django, confirm

I'm using Django in my project and I'm getting some problems with the `confirm` function in order to prevent item deletion from datatable option.

Despite cancelling in the confirm pop-up, the link still sends me to the default link href and the object is deleted.

This is my HTML:

```
<a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' id="elimina-objeto" onclick="confirmaEliminacion()" href="{% url 'eliminarQueja' queja.id %}">Eliminar</a>
```

And my JS:

```
function confirmaEliminacion() {
  var res = confirm("Va a eliminar el objeto seleccionado. Si desea continuar, pulse aceptar.");

  if (res) {
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("elimina-objeto").href = "#";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a small change to your HTML:

```
<a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' id="elimina-objeto" onclick="return confirmaEliminacion()" href="{% url 'eliminarQueja' queja.id %}">Eliminar</a>
```

Also, you should be returning `true` from your javascript function if the user wants to delete and follow the original href, and `false` if they do not want to delete.  Changing the href value itself is not necessary:

```
function confirmaEliminacion() {
  var res = confirm("Va a eliminar el objeto seleccionado. Si desea continuar, pulse aceptar.");
    if (res) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply perfect Morgan... you can't imagine the hours trying to make it works.

Thanks a lot.