# Remove elements from array of objects where ID matches regular expression in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have messages stored in state and few messages have _id key of GUID format, I am trying to remove it from the state using splice

```
this.state.messages : [{
   "_id":"1599906957896",
   "createdAt":"9/12/2020 10:35:57 AM +00:00",
   "text":"Message from Lakshay at 4:05",
   "user":{
      "_id":"6a59e693-a12a-4f7a-9a11-ad195492f57f",
      "avatar":"https://placeimg.com/140/140/any",
      "name":"student1 User"
   }
},
{
   "_id":"1599907249640",
   "createdAt":"9/12/2020 10:40:49 AM +00:00",
   "text":"Sending at 4:10",
   "user":{
      "_id":"6a59e693-a12a-4f7a-9a11-ad195492f57f",
      "avatar":"https://placeimg.com/140/140/any",
      "name":"student1 User"
   }
},
{
   "_id":"f5f535eb-d11b-4c7a-8992-3893e5d432e2",
   "createdAt":2020-09-12T10:40:40.911Z,
   "text":"Sending at 4:10",
   "user":{
      "_id":"6a59e693-a12a-4f7a-9a11-ad195492f57f",
      "avatar":"https://placeimg.com/140/140/any"
   }
}]
```

I want to remove messages that follow the pattern of GUID

```
var pattern = /^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i;
```

and push it back to state. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to cycle through the array and check for a match with `__id`, if yes, use splice to remove the object.

```js
let messages = [{
   "_id":"1599906957896",
   "createdAt":"9/12/2020 10:35:57 AM +00:00",
   "text":"Message from Lakshay at 4:05",
   "user":{
      "_id":"6a59e693-a12a-4f7a-9a11-ad195492f57f",
      "avatar":"https://placeimg.com/140/140/any",
      "name":"student1 User"
   }
},
{
   "_id":"1599907249640",
   "createdAt":"9/12/2020 10:40:49 AM +00:00",
   "text":"Sending at 4:10",
   "user":{
      "_id":"6a59e693-a12a-4f7a-9a11-ad195492f57f",
      "avatar":"https://placeimg.com/140/140/any",
      "name":"student1 User"
   }
},
{
   "_id":"f5f535eb-d11b-4c7a-8992-3893e5d432e2",
   "createdAt": '2020-09-12T10:40:40.911Z',
   "text":"Sending at 4:10",
   "user":{
      "_id":"6a59e693-a12a-4f7a-9a11-ad195492f57f",
      "avatar":"https://placeimg.com/140/140/any"
   }
}]

let pattern = /^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i


let result = messages.map((message, index) => !message['_id'].match(pattern) ? message : messages.splice(index, 1))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: No reason to use `let` here when you could use `const` is there?

Comment: I didn't understand this observation for an answer like that. It is not using a variable called messages, but a state object

Comment: Using `const`, `var` or `let` would not influence the answer at all

Comment: it's a matter of writing clear and idiomatic JavaScript.  If you don't intend to reassign the value, `const` is a better choice: `a single identifier should only be used to represent a single concept.` https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75

Comment: Any special reason for not doing the same in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127214/javascript-django-confirm-cancel-should-not-follow-href/48127829#48127829) ?

Comment: No, I only fixed what was missing in that case.  In your answer above, there's no real reason to change `var` to `let`.  If you're going to use the new declaration operators, might as well use the appropriate one, which is `const`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221374/discussion-between-matt-morgan-and-aks-jacoves).

Comment: Available! :^)!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is for you to use the filter method. Map would return an undefined in case the pattern does not match so you array would have an undefined instead of the original object.

```
const result = messages.filter(message => !message['_id'].match(pattern));
```